# To install Pandoc's manuals

Tags: macos, homebrew

I run `cabal install pandoc pandoc-citeproc` as described in the [manual](http://pandoc.org/installing.html#mac-os-x).
I get nothing from `man pandoc`. 
Pandoc exists in brew but I would like to know how you get pandoc by manuals too. 
I would like to read `man pandoc_markdown`.

How can you install pandoc with manuals?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Pandoc 1.15.0.4** was just released, will install the MAN pages during the cabal install process.  However, you need to make sure your MANPATH environment variable includes the cabal MAN page directory.  (On OSX, this is generally `$HOME/Library/Haskell/share/man`.)  Add to your

`~/.bashrc: MANPATH=$HOME/Library/Haskell/share/man:$MANPATH`

Answer (score 1):

There is `pandoc --help` as well as the [online documentation/user guide](http://pandoc.org/README.html). I have pandoc installed via Homebrew and I also have no `man` pages.

```
erik@Eriks-MBP:~$ man pandoc
No manual entry for pandoc
```